# How can I request a node error in my javascript front end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, backend

I want to do a validation when a user registers and I don't know how to show the error in the front end since I can't find a way to connect the back-end file that throws the error with the front-end that would be the one who sent the message

//login controller

```
const DBConnector = require('../database/db');
const path = require('path');

function login(req, res) {
    res.render(( path.join(__dirname, '/../views/login.html')));
}
async function registervalidate(req,res){
    const datos = req.body
    //register
    let user_exist = await DBConnector.query(`SELECT USER FROM usuarios WHERE USER = "${datos.username}"`);
    let gmail_exist = await DBConnector.query(`SELECT EMAIL FROM usuarios WHERE EMAIL = "${datos.gmail}"`)
    if(user_exist.length > 0){
        res.render('../views/login', {error: "User Already register"})
    }else if(gmail_exist.length > 0){
        res.send("gmail ya registrado, intenta con otro");
    }else{
        await DBConnector.query(`INSERT INTO usuarios (USER,EMAIL,PASSWORD) VALUES("${datos.username}", "${datos.gmail}","${datos.password}")`)
        console.log("datos guardados correctamente");   
    }
}
module.exports = {
    login,
    registervalidate
```

//javascript(front-end)

```
const signinBtn = document.querySelector('.signinbtn');
const signupBtn = document.querySelector('.signupbtn');
const formBx = document.querySelector('.formBx');
const body = document.querySelector('body');

signupBtn.onclick = function(){
    formBx.classList.add('active')
    body.classList.add('active')
}

signinBtn.onclick = function(){
    formBx.classList.remove('active')
    body.classList.remove('active')
}

if() {
    console.log("hola")
}
```

//index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const home = require('./routes/router');
const puerto = 3000;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');

//routes
app.use('/', home);

//middlewares

//iniciar la web
app.listen(puerto, () =>{
console.log('Pagina web iniciada correctamente http://localhost:3000/login')  
});
```

I thought that since the files were connected to each other, the javascript would recognize the error but it gave me a definition and it was very stupid since I tried to validate a variable that did not exist

Comment: Use chrome's fetch api

Comment: how i can get error with fetch api?

Comment: Use a route on your backend, respond with json or a status code, parse this on your frontend

Comment: Since you have ejs templating engine, you can try express-flash.